# How to fix Euclidean Distance function? (Movie Recommender)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, euclidean-distance

Something similar to this https://blazingedge.io/blog/movie-recommendation-javascript/

My ecDistance function is getting small similarity scores 
For example: .01 - 0059 and smaller. The logic is correct. What I think may be wrong is looping through all of the data and using it in user2 to compare each one in a loop.

ecDistance  Function takes in user1 which is from the command line or 
process.argv[2] and user2 all the of the movies.'

user2:

```
//object
[{
userId: 1
movieId:1
rating:4.5

}, ...]
```

```
function ecDistance(user1, user2) {
  let objRating = getComparedRating(user1, user2) // function that handles all the ratings that are the same from both users 
  let totoalOfSums = 0
  let tempSim = []
  //user2 is all of the users besides user one [{ userId:1 , movieId:1, rating:4.5}]
  for (let i = 0; i < user1.length; i++) { // user1 is what is taken in from  process.argv[2] {

    let diff = objRating.user1[i] - objRating.user2[i]
    let squared = diff * diff
    totalOfSums += squared
    let squareRootSum = Math.sqrt(totalofSums)
    let similarity = 1 / (1 + squareRootSum) // get the similarity score
    tempSim.push(similarity)
  }
}

function getComparedRating(user1, user2) {
  let userRating1 = []
  let userRating2 = []
  user2.forEach((data) => {
    user1.forEach((main) => {
/*
 if //they have the same movieId and if they are not the same user, 
push them in two different variables to use later on.
*/     
 if (data.movieId == main.movieId && data.userId !== main.userId) { 
        userRating1.push(main.rating)
        userRating2.push(data.rating)
      }
    })
  })
}

return {
  user1: userRating1,
  user2: userRating2
}
```

my expected Result are values, less than or equal to 1. (depending on the rating)

Comment: at prima vista, `for(let i =0; i < user1.length; i++)` lacks a `{`. btw, some formatting makes code better readable (and an IDE shows errors earlier ...)

Comment: Indentation.... please.

Comment: fixed errors and formatting(easier to read)

Comment: What exactly are you doing in this function? I cannot see anything close to a Euclidean distance. The only thing is the square and the square root, but they are used differently than what you would do for Euclidean distances. Can you describe what you are trying to do? I.e., calculate the distance of what vectors?

Comment: Something similar to this https://blazingedge.io/blog/movie-recommendation-javascript/

Comment: Your similarities are being updated every time the loop runs. Your totalofSums is not complete until the for loop is done, but it is being used as an arg to squareRootSum and being pushed directly to similarity. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes except I’m not sure for using the total. I’m using the formula in the article sqrt (sqr (x1+x2) + sqr (y1+y2)). I’m not sure I need it to do it for every user with the same rating score or for each on individually